# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Error while regenerating sessions

Tags: node.js, express, session, passport.js

I'm facing with the "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" Error in Express/Passportjs.
I do know that this error mainly occurs when callbacks has called twice, or more;,
but I don't understand why this error has occured. I've specified Error cases on the bottom.

Here's the code that I've wrote in app.js for the strategy setup

```
passport.use(new KakaoStrategy(
{
    clientID: kakao_key,
    callbackURL: '/userSchemaAPI/login/kakao/callback',
},
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    try {
        const foundUser = await User.findOne(
            {
                snsId: profile.id,
                provider: 'kakao',
            },
        );
        if (foundUser) {
            return done(null, foundUser);
        }
        else{
            return done(null, false, profile);
        } 
    } catch (error) {
        return done(error);
    }
},
),
```

);

this is the router code

```
router.get('/login/kakao', passport.authenticate('kakao'));

router.get('/login/kakao/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('kakao', function (err, user, info){
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) { 
            const { id } = info;
            req.session.joinUser = {
                snsId: id,
                email: info._json.kakao_account.email,
                username: info._json.properties.nickname,
            };
            return req.session.save(() => {
                res.redirect('/userSchemaAPI/register/kakao');
            });
        }
    return req.login(user, function (error){
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

I try to register new user when user hasn't registered in our DB. here's the
code when POST request has called in routes '/userSchemaAPI/register/kakao' -

```
module.exports.createNewKakaoUser = async(req,res,next)=>{
try {
    const { snsId, username, email } = req.session.joinUser;  
    const user = await User.create({
        provider : 'kakao',
        snsId : snsId,
        email: email,
        username: req.body.username || username,
    });
    req.session.regenerate(() => { 
        req.login(user, (error) => { 
            if (error) {
                return next(error);
            }
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    next(error);
}
```

}

There's 2 major Errors that I am currently facing with.

1. I can't directly logIn when my info is already in DB.
2. I succeeded to register my Info in DB, but server makes an "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" Error while logging in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will continue later after next is handled if you don't return

```
req.session.regenerate(() => { 
    req.login(user, (error) => { 
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
        return res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```